# XPATH can't find a way to find a static and a dynamic value in 1 TR (Table Row)

Tags: xpath

The source is:

https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/64161

What I tried is this:

```
//tr[contains(.,"order id")
```

But I needed the second part, so what I tried is this then:

```
//*[contains(text(),'order id')][1] and //*[contains(text(),'[^0-9]')]

${variable}= //*[contains(text(),'order id')][1] and //*[contains(text(),'[^0-9]')]
```

Comment: I do not see a single tr on entire HTML of the link which you've shared

Comment: true. this gets me closer but.... //div[contains(text(), 'order id')]/../following-sibling::div

Comment: even closer:  //div[contains(text(), 'order id')]/../following-sibling::div[1]

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
//div[contains(text(), 'order id')]/../descendant::div[2]
```